# SQL query summary report groupby status and calculate difference time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hi all i need show some report, but i don't have solution for this result.
Please help me guide solution for Query this result.

This is my table (log)

[image: This is my table (log)]

I need to write SQL query to generate the following results:
[image: I need to write SQL query to generate the following results]

Please guide me,
Thank you all answers.

Comment: Can you setup an sql fiddle?

Comment: I can't understand what's behind of your results as `Being Failed` and `Last OK` !! - And please select one of MySQL or SQL Server in your tags.

Comment: What you are grouping at? I see 4 equal rows.

Comment: Hi all,

#shA.t  : This query for SQL Server(2008R2)  and Begin Failed is value=1, Last OK is value=0 i need calculate difference time between Failed to Ok.

#Bogdan Bogdanov : i think i need grouping status and value for  calculate difference time between Failed to Ok.

#Felix Pamittan : Sorry i never use sql fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Island and Gaps problem which can be solved by using `ROW_NUMBER`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98cda2/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NODE, STATUS ORDER BY DATE_TIME)
                - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NODE, STATUS, VALUE ORDER BY DATE_TIME)
    FROM [Log]
),
CteMinMax AS(
    SELECT
        NODE,
        STATUS,
        VALUE,
        MIN_DATE_TIME = MIN(DATE_TIME),
        MAX_DATE_TIME = MAX(DATE_TIME)
    FROM Cte 
    GROUP BY 
        NODE, STATUS, VALUE, grp
)
SELECT
    NODE,
    STATUS,
    VALUE,
    [Begin Failed]  = cmm.MIN_DATE_TIME,
    [Last OK]       = x.MIN_DATE_TIME,
    [Time/Minute]   = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, cmm.MIN_DATE_TIME, x.MIN_DATE_TIME)
FROM CteMinMax cmm
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 MIN_DATE_TIME
    FROM CteMinMax
    WHERE
        NODE = cmm.NODE
        AND STATUS = cmm.STATUS
        AND VALUE = 0
        AND MIN_DATE_TIME > cmm.MIN_DATE_TIME
) x
WHERE cmm.VALUE = 1
```

**RESULT**

```
| NODE |         STATUS | VALUE |               Begin Failed |                    Last OK | Time/Minute |
|------|----------------|-------|----------------------------|----------------------------|-------------|
|    A | SQL Connection |     1 | December, 02 2015 14:02:00 | December, 02 2015 14:04:00 |           2 |
|    A | SQL Connection |     1 | December, 02 2015 14:05:00 | December, 02 2015 14:08:00 |           3 |
|    A | SQL Connection |     1 | December, 02 2015 14:12:00 | December, 02 2015 14:15:00 |           3 |
|    A | SQL Connection |     1 | December, 02 2015 14:17:00 | December, 02 2015 14:18:00 |           1 |
```

Comment: Felix Pamittan Thank you for support ,
i will try this query and update result to you soon.

Comment: Hi Felix Pamittan, It working fine.
Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Glad to have been of help.